# Neural Network misclassification using logistic function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've been training a fully connected neural network I've developed so that it can learn the [XOR problem](http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php). I got succesful results using hyperbolic tangent and ReLU as [activation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), this is, the network output matched with the outputs of the XOR truth table. Still, as far as I understand, the activation function should be chosen taking into account the input range, which in this case is $[0, 1]$. As that range is the active input range of the logistic function I wanted to use the latter as activation function.

Using the logistic function I get completely random results, as thay are close to $0.5$ in all cases, i.e. any input combination of $0$'s and $1$'s results in a value close to $0.5$. This leads me to think that the each output is just a guess.

What I don't understand is **why if my input is bounded in the $[0, 1]$ range it works with activation functions with output range of $(-1, 1)$ or $[0, +inf)$ and not $(0, 1)$**? Does my reasoning make sense or am I missing something?

Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT:** I've tested another set of outputs for the same group of inputs, more specifically `inputs = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]` and `outputs = [[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]]`, and get correct results:

`[0, 0] --> [ 0.99999543, 0.99488362]
[0, 1] --> [ 9.67808797e-01, 4.01490200e-04]
[1, 0] --> [ 3.19309525e-05, 9.92688220e-01]
[1, 1] --> [ 0.0216361, 0.0097268]`

Other cases with 2 or more outputs work as well, but I still can make the XOR problem, with one output, work. Why would the network, using logistic functions as activations, classify samples correctly when having 2 or more outputs and not when there is only one?

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), the activation function should be [sigmoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). I understand this as inputs of [0,+inf] to yield [0,1] in the (y-axis) output.

Comment: @Carl, yes I agree, but what happens with ReLUs? They still can be used as activation functions, can't they? I've edited the post, the last paragraph, I mixed up. My bad.

Comment: ReLUs is just a [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), AKA, positive ramp; max[0,x], for which input of [-inf,+inf] yields an output of [0,+inf]. Why useful, don't know, not my area.

Comment: @Carl, thanks for pointing that out. Still, when I use the tanh, which is a sigmoid, the NN correctly classifies new data. I don't know why the logistic function does not work in this case, as the output I'm looking for is the same as the output the logistic provides.

Comment: Logistic-1/2 is sigmoidal, logistic is not. Rectifiers function used to convert alternating current to direct current and 4 rectifiers, suitably arranged, are the absolute value function; |x|. Logistic is derivative of softplus, where softplus is smooth approximation to rectifier.

Comment: Sorry, 2*logistic-1 is sigmoidal. not logistic -1/2, but 2*(logistic-1/2). Also, rectifiers have better training characteristics than sigmoidal. Rectifiers, and diodes (which are also rectifying) are basic logic circuit elements, to see how electrical diodes can be used to make an XOR circuit see [link](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/q5y7c5/xor-using-diodes/).

Comment: @Carl, I've used ReLUs because of its [advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Advantages) over sigmoids. Still my problem is with the logistic sigmoid function. As the Wikipedia article you share states, sigmoids generally go from 0 to 1 or from -1 to 1. So using the logistic function as it is should work.

Comment: Already answered. Logistic is not sigmoidal. The y-axis should be transformed to be -1 to 1 over x is from -inf to +inf, or, y goes from 0 to 1 for x goes from 0 to +inf. Then is will be sigmoidal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: $\text{Logistic}(0)=0.5$, $\text{Sigmoidal(0)}=0$. Also note, $2\text{Logistic}(0)-1=0$, and one can combine a pair of logistic functions to obtain $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I've made the necessary changes to meet what you state here and in previous comments. Now it works correctly. Thanks for your help.